# constructor() and super() methods in Javascript

Tags: javascript, react-native, constructor, super

I'm currently learning how to build iOS apps using React Native. I have some experience in Javascript and HTML (not a whole lot, I'm coming straight from years of Swift and Objective-C). I am working through an example code snippet about creating stateful components using (a) property initializer or (b) the constructor method. Here are my code snippets for both respectively.

I completely understand the property initializer way of doing it. I'm confused on how the constructor way of doing it works. My question is:

1. What do the constructor and super methods do? I understand that these are not part of React Native, rather of Javascript itself.
2. Would there be a reason you would pick the property initializer way over the constructor method or vice versa?

Thanks!
Mohammad

```
// Property Initiliazer Way of Doing It
class PropertyInitializerStatefulComponent extends React.Component {

    // 1. State is initialized when a component is created as demonstrated below
    // 2. Once initialized, it is avalable as a this.state.
    state = {

        year: 2019,
        name: 'Johnny Appleseed',
        colors: ['blue']

    }

    render() {

        // Implementation of Point 2
        return(
            <View>
                <Text>My name is  {this.state.name}</Text>
                <Text>The year is: {this.state.year}</Text>
                <Text>My favorite colors are: {this.state.colors[0]}</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

```
// Making a stateful component using the constructor method...

class ConstructorStatefulComponent extends React.Component {

    // ??
    constructor() {

        // ??
        super() 
        this.state = {

            year: 2019,
            name: 'Johnny Appleseed',
            colors: ['blue']

        }
    }

    render() {

        // Implementation of Point 2
        return(
            <View>
                <Text>My name is  {this.state.name}</Text>
                <Text>The year is: {this.state.year}</Text>
                <Text>My favorite colors are: {this.state.colors[0]}</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`super()` is used to call the parent's function.

In your code, you wrote `super()` in the constructor so it runs the `constructor()` of `React.Component`.

You can use `super()` not only in the `constructor` but also in the other functions.

For example, the parent class(React.Component in your code) has a method `func1()` and it was defined like the following code.

```
function func1() {
  this.a = 0;
  this.b = 0;
}
```

But you need to set another property `c` in the `func1()` of the child class. In that case you should redefine the `func1` in the child class and it should be the following.

```
function func1() {
  super.func1(); // it will set a and b as 0
  this.c = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The concept of super in Javascript just clicked with the example!

Answer (score 0):

If you are coming from Objective C:

- `constructor` is `-(id)init;`
- `super()` inside `constructor` is `[super init]`

This is simplified a bit, but good enough for the fragment you posted. The missing piece is:

- If you return a non-primitive value from a constructor, `new` operator will not return a *new* value but the passed one; you would do this by overriding `+(id)alloc`.
- You can also use `super` to access other methods on the parent class. For example, `super.foo(42)` would be `[super foo:42]`.

Answer (score 0):

1. `constructor()` runs on new instantiations of the object, to prepare it. When extending a class, the `super()` function call is for the parent class's constructor. This is why you cannot use `this` anywhere until you've called super, your class hasn't been fully instantiated yet
2. Property initialization outside of the constructor is just syntactic sugar. It's newer to JavaScript (sometime within the last few years), but it's functionally equivalent to initializing properties in the `constructor()`

Comment: Got it! Thanks for explaining the constructor method and how it works!

Answer (score 0):

[`super`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super#Using_super_in_classes) is required if you're extending from another class.

As for the `constructor` vs [`field declaration`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields#field-declarations), the only difference is that the field declaration isn't part of the JS specs yet; React supports it though.